# Issue in message security in WCF using certificate authentication

Tags: wcf, security

I have WCF service where I have implemented message security using certificate. But when I try to connect WCF service from my client application, I am getting following error :

**The caller was not authenticated by the service.**

My configuration settings are as below :

Service Settings :

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HostService));
NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
tcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IHostService), tcpBinding, "net.tcp://192.168.39.28:8000/HostService");
host.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "server_cert");
```

Client Settings :

```
NetTcpBinding tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
tcpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
DuplexChannelFactory<IHostService> serviceFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IHostService>(new InstanceContext(MainWindow), tcpBinding, "net.tcp://192.168.39.28:8000/HostService");
serviceFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "client_cert");
serviceFactory.CreateChannel();
```

where I have created server_cert and client_cert certificates using makecert command. Can you please guide me what I missed ?

Answer (score 0):

debugging certificate related issue is a big pain, I highly recommend to use wireshark. in your case, it's possible you client side didn't even send out the certificate. if the client cert is signed by another cert(s), make sure put it(them) into the trusted root on both client and server.

Comment: how to put Certificate in trusted root on both client and server. what do u mean by trusted root ? is it any folder location ? any special way require to put Certificate in trusted root or just we can copy the certificate manually ?

Comment: @SeaChange : I got solution for this issue in following link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647171.aspx It explained all the steps to create and install certificate in store.